# Array of the last five months

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an array of the last five months, but the results are weird.....
I have this array for the months:

```
    var month = []; 
    month[0] = "January";
    month[1] = "February";
    month[2] = "March";
    month[3] = "April";
    month[4] = "May";
    month[5] = "June";
    month[6] = "July";
    month[7] = "August";
    month[8] = "September";
    month[9] = "October";
    month[10] = "November";
    month[11] = "December";
```

I use this to pull in my charts:

```
    var chartLabels = [];
    var d = new Date();
    for (var m_month = 0; m_month < 5; m_month++){
        chartLabels[m_month] = month[d.getMonth()];
            d.setMonth(d.getMonth()-1);
    }
```

It works today (4/1), but it didn't work yesterday. If you run it with var d = new Date(2016,3,30), you'll get March twice in the results. I tried a while statement for a previous month, but it didn't work.

```
    var d = new Date(2016, 03, 30);
    for (var m_month = 0; m_month < 5; m_month++){
        //console.log(d);
        chartLabels[m_month] = month[d.getMonth()];
        while (chartLabels[m_month] == month[d.getMonth]){
            d.setMonth(d.getMonth()-1);
        }
        console.log(d);
    }
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

February 30th is in March :). You need to set the day-of-month to 1 before starting.

```
var chartLabels = [];
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(1); // <---- this
for (var m_month = 0; m_month < 5; m_month++){
    chartLabels[m_month] = month[d.getMonth()];
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth()-1);
}
```

Comment: It makes sense, but it doesn't make sense. Thanks. That will do it.